# Removing query params causing issue on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I have a URL with a  query string attached to it. After the page loads, I am removing the query param using

`history.replaceState("","",location.href.substring(0,location.href.indexOf("?")))`

But when user hit refresh button its displaying error screen from my application since expected query param was not there in URL. I can use post action there but I would like to avoid query params with page refresh working fine. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Consider caching last query for each session and url, and execute it when a page is requested without query params. It is not a good practice since breaks rest principle (statelessness) and makes such links unshareable, but will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a query parameter and then removing it, then the user hit's refresh and there is an error saying it's expecting a query parameter, then your code (and logic) is lacking.

My suggestion, if you want to avoid query parameter after the page initially loaded, is to save the parameter in a cookie or even a session if there is code-behind. Then if the user refreshes without the query parameter, check if the cookie exists, if the cookie exists, show them the page normally, if not, instruct them that they did not visit the URL through the correct channels.

However, like  I mentioned, I think your logic here is flawed, because if the user wants to share your URL to the outside world, and you removed the key piece of information that makes the page load successfully, then you will have a lot of confused people on your hands

edit

You might want to investigate SEO friendly URL's to pass your query in to, so instead of: yoururl.com/?firstname=joe you can do yoururl.com/firstname/joe